# Javascript print div not working in safari web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

This is the code I used, and it works fine in firefox and chrome, unfortunately safari is not supporting this The dialogue box is closing immediately after appearing. Any solution to this problem?

```
 var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
 mywindow.document.write(
   '<html style="background-color: white;"><head><title></title>');
 mywindow.document.write(
   '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/queue.css">'
 );
 mywindow.document.write(
   '</head><body style="background-color: white !important;padding-top:15px;margin:2">'
 );
 mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('forprint').innerHTML);
 mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
 mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
 mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
 mywindow.print();
 mywindow.close();
 return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Safari blocks calls to window.open() (async call) call window.open first before making an asnyc call and then set the location (when the promise has been resolved):

```
var newWindow = window.open();
var url = "[YOURURL]";

service.getUrl().then(function(url) {
     newWindow.location = url;
});
```